# a featured content slider like this

Tags: plugin-recommendation, slideshow

I have seen one of the best featured content slider here:
http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Polished/

Can you recommend me a plugin to replicate it in my own wp theme?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this plugin, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-slider-for-featured-content

Answer (score 1):

Not a plugin but easy to integrate into your wp theme: [jQuery Image Gallery with jCarousel](http://www.queness.com/post/3036/create-a-custom-jquery-image-gallery-with-jcarousel). You'll just have to insert special queries to get the images commimg from posts or even special categories or even custom post type 'featured'.